# can a figure in a paper be titled "questions respective [topic] ?"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, titles, science

I am currently writing a scientific paper in cooperation with multiple co-authors, some of them being more experienced than me. In a figure, questionnaire results are shown.

One of my more experienced co-authors chose the title **"questions respective [topic]"**, which I find somehow unsettling, even though I cannot think of a definite rule for this.

Is entitling a figure in this fashion correct use of the word **"respective"**?
If not, what kind of title would be appropriate?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: while being titled "questions ...", the figure actually contains answers to questions.

Comment: I assume it's a rather archaic way of saying _question about ..._? Maybe you could use _question regarding ..._.

Comment: I agree with @oerkelens regarding "regarding". My question is: "does the figure actually depict questions or answers"?

Comment: it is showing answers. I've edited my question.

Comment: The label looks cryptic. Without examining the content of the paper, it would be hard to provide a definitive alternative or to determine what was intended by the cryptic label.